# Stack site for detectives?

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

Does a stack subsite exist for the aforementioned class of individuals or those interested in that field? Does a subsite along these lines already exist?

Comment: Do you mean no such site currently exists?

Comment: There is currently no such site. A list of our sites is available at http://stackexchange.com/sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the list of all the current Stack Exchange sites at [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

To propose a new site, go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).